# Booting into Mac USB Image from Grub2

Tags: macos, boot, grub, grub2

I have an Intel Macbook currently running ArchLinux that I would like to restore to running MacOSX. I have a Yosemite recovery USB but I am having difficulty getting the Grub2 bootloader on the machine to boot into it.

So far I have something like:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,gpt2)
grub> chainloader /System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi
```

But that gives me a `premature end of file` error. Has anyone had success booting into into an OSX recovery USB in this way?

Comment: Have you tried [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/HT201314)?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue (was running Lubuntu). To fix, I booted into internet recovery mode (cmd-r when starting up), and waited for the Internet Recovery to load. I used the recovery tools to wipe the internal SSD completely (choosing Mac OS Extended (Journaled)).

Then I restarted, with my boot USB plugged in - I think I held cmd-shift-R, or cmd-R. I got the flashing question mark folder, but I removed and re-inserted the flash drive and was greeted with the Apple logo. After some loading, I got into the recovery page again, and chose the option to install macOS and selected the boot USB.

Internet Recovery should have allowed me to install macOS directly from the Internet, but it's a 2010 MacBook Air that wants to try install Lion, and it doesn't work.